# "setTimeout" in card shuffling script

Tags: javascript, settimeout, puzzle

hope this question won't get my arse flamed.
I'm currently working on a jigsaw-puzzle game and i got all my basic code on point. Now, to make it more "professional", I'd like to implement a function to shuffle all the cards.
As for the shuffling algorithm, I'm well prepared and i already got one, but, in order to make it more eye-pleasant, I'd like to make the script **stop** for a few milliseconds after every successful card-swap, instad of showing the puzzle already all shuffled after the click of a button, wich is what's happening now (even if I already tried to use the "setTimeout" function).

My script is the following, hope someone can help me sort this out:

```
function shuffleCards() {
    var temp;

    for ( var i=0 ; i<50 ; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

            if (temp === 1)
                move( "t1" );
            else if (temp === 2)
                move( "t2" );
            else if (temp === 3)
                move( "t3" );           
        } , 500);
    }
}
```

( FYI: The draw() function is called at the end of the move() function )

Comment: your question won't get you flamed, not posting any html or the move function will though :)

Comment: Well, I don't see that as necessary in order to solve my problem. All I gotta do is set a pause interval in between of every iteration of my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `setTimeout` inside for loop will performe all actions altogether with a delay of 500ms.
Try `setInteval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
function shuffleCards() {
        var temp;
        var i=0;
        var shuffle = setInterval(function () {
            if (i < 50) {
                i++;
                temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                if (temp === 1)
                    move("t1");
                else if (temp === 2)
                    move("t2");
                else if (temp === 3)
                    move("t3");
            } else {
                clearInterval(shuffle);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try.
Just one question about your solution:
Why didn't you use a for loop as I did? Is it uncorrect/futile or something?

Comment: your setTimeout inside for loop will performe all actions altogether with a delay of 500ms, unless you use closure

Comment: Oh thanks, is that documented somewhere, so I could study the behavior of _setTimeout_ ?

Comment: check it : http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside-a

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to delay actions following the card shuffling, you could use a recursive approach with a callback at the end:

```
function shuffleCardsWait( i, ms, limit, cb ) {
  var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  if (temp === 1)
    move( "t1" );
  else if (temp === 2)
    move( "t2" );
  else if (temp === 3)
    move( "t3" );
  if ( i < limit ) {
    setTimeout( function( ) {
      i++;
      shuffleCardsWait( i, ms, limit, cb );
    }, ms );
  } else {
   if ( cb ) cb( );
  }
}
```